# Constructing Measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R_0^+ \text{ be an integrable function}$
a) $\phi(Y) =\int_Yfd \lambda$
$Y \text{ is an element of the borel-}\sigma-\text algebra$
$\lambda  \text{ is the lebesuge measure}$
I already proofed that $\phi$ is a well defined measure. Now I need to show that there exists a measure $\phi$ for the borel-$\sigma-algebra$ with the following properties.
1. $\theta(\mathbb R)=1$
2. $N\subset \mathbb R \text{ is a zero set exactly when }\text{ N is a zero set for } \lambda$

Comment: Use that $f$ is integrable, so its integral over $\mathbb R$ is finite.

Comment: maybe you could consider $ce^{-x^2}$ with suitable positive constant and thus your first condition is satisfied. For the second note that the function we have is strictly positive on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I solved that problem (;